# Apache Jena throws exception when performing a SPARQL query with a VALUES block

Tags: sparql, jena

I'm trying to run a query with Apache Jena 3.13.1. Such query uses the [VALUES](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data-examples) block so that I can assign the IRIs of many resources to one of its parameters. Please, see the example below.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.jena.query.ParameterizedSparqlString;
import org.apache.jena.query.Query;

List<Resource> selected = ...
final ParameterizedSparqlString pss = new ParameterizedSparqlString("PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> SELECT DISTINCT ?r WHERE { VALUES ?c {?cValues} { ?r dcterms:subject ?d. ?c a skos:Concept ; skos:narrower+ ?d } UNION { ?r dcterms:subject ?c . }}");
pss.setValues("cValues", selected);
System.out.println(pss.toString());
final Query query = pss.asQuery();
```

The problem I have is when I run such piece of code the 4th. line outputs to the console the following query:

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?r WHERE {
    VALUES ?c {(<http://a.url.com/x#a>)}
    { ?r dcterms:subject ?d. ?c a skos:Concept ; skos:narrower+ ?d }
    UNION
    { ?r dcterms:subject ?c . }
}
```

Then, when the 5th line executes I get an exception, because you should not have parenthesis delimiting VALUES's parameters in the query above.

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> SELECT DISTINCT ?r WHERE { VALUES ?c {(<http://a.url.com/x#a>)} { ?r dcterms:subject ?d. ?c a skos:Concept ; skos:narrower+ ?d } UNION { ?r dcterms:subject ?c . }}
org.apache.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 135.
Was expecting one of:
    <IRIref> ...
    <PNAME_NS> ...
    <PNAME_LN> ...
    "undef" ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    <INTEGER> ...
    <DECIMAL> ...
    <DOUBLE> ...
    <INTEGER_POSITIVE> ...
    <DECIMAL_POSITIVE> ...
    <DOUBLE_POSITIVE> ...
    <INTEGER_NEGATIVE> ...
    <DECIMAL_NEGATIVE> ...
    <DOUBLE_NEGATIVE> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL1> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL2> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL_LONG1> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL_LONG2> ...
    "}" ...

    at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11.perform(ParserSPARQL11.java:100)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11.parse$(ParserSPARQL11.java:52)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.SPARQLParser.parse(SPARQLParser.java:34)
    at org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory.parse(QueryFactory.java:147)
    at org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:52)
    at org.apache.jena.query.ParameterizedSparqlString.asQuery(ParameterizedSparqlString.java:1435)
    at org.apache.jena.query.ParameterizedSparqlString.asQuery(ParameterizedSparqlString.java:1422)
```

My question is: am I using Jena API correctly to do what I want? If I am, this may be a bug. Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: you're using Jena correctly, but your SPARQL query is not having the correct syntax. The issue is with `VALUES`, when you use brackets for the value itself, you also have to do it for the variable: `VALUES (?c) {(<http://a.url.com/x#a>)}` - clearly, brackets are only really necessary for tuples, i.e. in your case you could also do `VALUES ?c {<http://a.url.com/x#a>}` - but you never can mix it up

Comment: Thank you! Changing my query from `VALUES ?c {?cValues}` to `VALUES (?c) {?cValues}` solved the issue.